# In C# can I wrap Func to cache results

Tags: c#, func

I've written code to return a `Func<int, long>` that computes a sequence of integers. I'd like to cache intermediate results in the most elegant way possible. Currently my code looks like this:

```
private static Func<int, long> A237585() {
    Func<int, long> A = null;
    Func<int, long> B = null;
    Func<int, long> C = null;
    A = CreateCachingFunc((n) => n == 0 ? 0 : B(n-1));
    B = CreateCachingFunc((n) => C(n) + (n == 1 ? 1 : 0));
    C = CreateCachingFunc(CreateSumProductPartitionSelect(A, (n, k) => Choose(n + k - 1, k)));
    return A;
}

private static Func<int, long> CreateCachingFunc(Func<int, long> original)
{
    var cache = new List<long>();
    Func<int, long> cachedVersion = (n) =>
    {
        while (n >= cache.Count) cache.Add(original(cache.Count));
        return cache[n];
    };
    return cachedVersion;
}
```

I'd like it to look something like this:

```
private static Func<int, long> A237585() {
    CachedFunc<long> A = null;
    CachedFunc<long> B = null;
    CachedFunc<long> C = null;
    A = (n) => n == 0 ? 0 : B(n-1);
    B = (n) => C(n) + (n == 1 ? 1 : 0);
    C = CreateSumProductPartitionSelect(A, (n, k) => Choose(n + k - 1, k));
    return A;
}
```

Is that possible? How would I write CachedFunc to implicitly convert the CachedFunc back to a Func on return, and implicitly convert (wrap) the anonymous lambdas into cached versions? If it's not possible, what's the nicest looking way to wrap my functions? I'd like the top level code to look as simple as I can.

Comment: Is this some kind of home work? What's wrong with your code? How do you measure "most elegant" and "as simple as I can"?

Comment: This is called memoization.

Comment: I'm finding new interesting sequences to add to OEIS. This one's https://oeis.org/draft/A237585. In general I'd like to have a very simple looking piece of code for the main description with a link to the rest of the implementation.

Comment: You can use AOP for this. If you don't want to roll out your own solution for this, there are memoization libraries out there like MbCache (https://code.google.com/p/mbcache/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first turn your existing memoization implementation that uses a lambda into an explicit capture class (this is almost identical to what the C# compiler creates automatically when it sees a lambda):

```
class CachedFunc<T>
{
     private List<T> cache;
     private Func<int, T> original;
     private T Call(int n)
     {
        while (n >= cache.Count) cache.Add(original(cache.Count));
        return cache[n];
     }

     public static Func<int, long> Create(Func<int, T> original)
     {
         return new CachedFunc<T>() { cache = new List<T>(), original = original }.Call;
     }
}
```

Now, we just need to add implicit conversion:

```
class CachedFunc<T>
{
     private List<T> cache;
     private Func<int, T> original;
     private T Call(int n) {
        while (n >= cache.Count) cache.Add(original(cache.Count));
        return cache[n];
     }

     public static implicit operator CachingFunc<T>(Func<int, T> original)
     {
         return new CachedFunc<T>() { cache = new List<T>(), original = original };
     }

     public static implicit operator Func<int, T>(CachingFunc<T> memo)
     {
         return memo.Call;
     }
}
```

Comment: Here's code using a CachedFunc<long> and what errors I'm getting:  
  
    CachedFunc<long> A = null;  
    CachedFunc<long> B = null;  
    CachedFunc<long> C = null;  
    A = new Func<int, long>((n) => n == 0 ? 0 : B(n - 1));  
    B = (n) => C(n) + (n == 1 ? 1 : 0);  
    C = CreateSumProductPartitionSelect(A, (n, k) => Choose(n + k - 1, k));  
    return A;  
  
Assigning A says "B is a variable but is used like a method".  
Assigning B says "Cannot convert lambda expression to type CachedFunc<long> because it is not a delegate type".  
Assigning C works just fine.

Comment: @Guy: You can't make a user-defined object invocable in C#.  But it shouldn't be much trouble to use `B.Call(n-1)` (make it public of course).  And an extension method might be helpful for assigning these objects from lambdas.

Comment: @Guy: BTW, I'm not sure what's so bad about your original code, if you shorten the name `CreateCachingFunc` to e.g. `memo`